# Contractible $T_2$-space without subspace homeomorphic to it

Tags: gn.general-topology

This is an update to an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323629/does-every-connected-t-2-space-x-have-a-proper-subspace-homeomorphic-to-x).

Is there a contractible $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ on more than $1$ point such that no proper subspace of $X$ is homeomorphic to $X$?

Comment: Just a remark: no example can be provided in the category of compact topological manifolds of dimension $>0$. In fact, compact manifolds with boundary are *never* co-hopfian. On the other hand, compact manifolds without boundary are *always* co-hopfian, but they are never contractible (for instance, because the top cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients does not vanish).

Comment: See K VARADARAJAN *Hopfian and co-hopfian objects* (1992) https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/13295642.pdf

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323705/contractible-t-2-space-without-subspace-homeomorphic-to-it#comment807661_323705): [article page](http://mat.uab.cat/pubmat/articles/view_doi/10.5565/PUBLMAT_36192_21) and [MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1179618).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of such contractible (compact metrizable) space can be constructed as follows.

Let $K$ be [the Cook continuum](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm60/fm60123.pdf). It has the property that any continuous map $f:C\to K$ defined on a subcontinuum $C\subset K$ is either constant or the identity inclusion. Take any countable family $(K_{n,m})_{n,m\in\omega}$ of pairwise disjoint non-degenerate subcontinua of $K$. For every $n,m\in\omega$ let $\hat K_{n,m}=K_{n,m}\times [0,1]/(K_{n,m}\times\{0\})$ be the cone over $K_{n,m}$ with vertex $v_{n,m}$.

Let $X_0=\hat K_{0,0}$. For every $n\in\mathbb N$ we shall construct a compact metrizable contractible space $X_n$ that contain the space $X_{n-1}$ as a deformation retract. Assume that for some $n\in\mathbb N$ a space $X_{n-1}$ has been contructed. Fix any function $f_n:\omega\to X_{n-1}$ with dense image $f_n(\omega)$ in $X_{n-1}$. Let $X_n$ be the quotient space of the disjoint union $X_{n-1}\cup\bigcup_{m\in\omega}\hat K_{n,m}$ by the equivalence relation that identifies the vertex $v_{n,m}$ of each cone $\hat K_{n,m}$ with the point $f_n(m)$. The space $X_n$ has a natural compact metrizable topology such that $X_{n-1}$ is a reformation retract of $X_n$. This compeletes the inductive step.

Then the inverse limit $X=\varprojlim X_n$ is a contractible compact Hausdorff space such that every proper subspace $P$ of $X$ is not homeomorphic to $X$. This is because $P$ is either non-compact or not dense in $X$ and hence contains no subset homeomorphic to the continuum $K_{n,m}$ for suitable (large) numbers $n,m$.

Comment: I don't see why you take the tree to be rooted, the root plays no role (ah I see: just to define its boundary as the set of branches, even if the resulting compactification does not depend on the choice of root). Also, you need to assume, in addition to your assumption, that $T$ equals the convex hull of its subset of branching points. Otherwise you could have a infinite branch and the resulting tree would be non-cohopfian.

Comment: Take a tree as you think of, and glue an "isolated" geodesic ray to the root (assuming that this does not destroy 2). If you don't know what a convex hull is, my additional condition is equivalent to the condition that the set of vertices of degree 2, endowed with the induced graph structure, has no infinite component.

Comment: Ah, I would never have thought of a vertex of degree as a branching point! In any case the simplest is to assume that every vertex has degree $\ge 3$.

Comment: It seems to me that many easily defined trees of the described type produce (induce) space which does have a proper homeomorphic subspace. I feel that it is still an annoying challenge to define one which does not (possibly, there is no such tree of the given type). The "secret" of counterexamples is to have a different root.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I guess you can imagine a subtree with many vertices of degree 2, isomorphic to the larger tree (say, in which all edges have length 2 in the original tree). I didn't see this subtlety either. (Nothing to do with the root anyway, it plays no role.)

Comment: Thinking twice: if $S,T$ are infinite trees of finite degree and $S',T'$ their end compactification, if $T$ has the property that it has finitely many vertices of each given degree, then $S'$ is homeomorphic to a proper subset of $T'$ (closure of some subtree of $T$).

Comment: Would you link somewhere about the Cook continuum?

Comment: @YCor, "Nothing to do with the root anyway, it plays no role." -- for your approach, I guess. Choosing a different root made things actually trivial (I was just using a gentle language). In some examples, any new root different from the original one leads to a sub-subtree homeomorphic to the original tree.

Comment: @WlodAA I mean that to define a tree $T$ with the given axioms (from the erased post: finite degree, everywhere $\ge 3$, and at most one vertex of any given degree) and considering $\bar{T}$ is not related to any choice of root. (Still, the natural notion(s) of subtree is not the same in the non-rooted case and in the rooted case.)

Comment: @YCor, the notion of the root is here just a useful **auxiliary** notion, that's all.

Comment: @WlodAA Perfect, we agree.